# Define and set options for custom WebViewClient class in Android

Tags: java, android, android-webview, webviewclient

I have created a custom `WebViewClient` class that has very limited interaction - it can only load Amazon URLs and doesn't allow clicking of links. (`amzn.to` and `smile.amazon` are allowed as they redirect)

```
package com.domain.mypackage;

import android.net.Uri;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.webkit.WebResourceRequest;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;

public class nonInteractiveWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {

    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideKeyEvent (WebView view, KeyEvent event) {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, WebResourceRequest request) {
        String host = Uri.parse(view.getUrl()).getHost();

        if ("amzn.to".equals(host)) {
            return false;
        } else if (host != null && host.matches("(?i)^smile\\.amazon.*")) {
            return false;
        } else {
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

I want to enhance this new class so that if I enable an option it *will* allow clicking of links, but only Amazon links. I have therefore added a boolean that I want to be able to set from the calling Activity.

```
package com.domain.mypackage;

import android.net.Uri;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.webkit.WebResourceRequest;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;

public class nonInteractiveWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {

    public boolean canBrowseAmazonSites = false;

    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideKeyEvent (WebView view, KeyEvent event) {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, WebResourceRequest request) {
        String host = Uri.parse(view.getUrl()).getHost();

        if ("amzn.to".equals(host)) {
            return false;
        } else if (host != null && host.matches("(?i)^smile\\.amazon.*")) {
            return false;
        // Allow clicking of Amazon links
        } else if ( canBrowseAmazonSites && host != null && ( host.matches("(?i)^smile\\.amazon.*") || host.matches("(?i)^www\\.amazon.*") ) ) {
            return false;
        } else {
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

I create the `WecViewClient` in the calling Acttivity as follows:

```
    viewBinding.amazonWebview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    viewBinding.amazonWebview.getSettings().setSupportZoom(true);
    viewBinding.amazonWebview.setWebViewClient(new nonInteractiveWebViewClient() {
        @Override
        public void onPageStarted(WebView _param1, String _param2, Bitmap _param3) {
            super.onPageStarted(_param1, _param2, _param3);
            viewBinding.progressBar.setIndeterminate(true);
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView _param1, String _param2) {
            super.onPageFinished(_param1, _param2);
            viewBinding.progressBar.setIndeterminate(false);
        }

    });
```

But I cannot work out how to set my Boolean from within the Activity.

I did wonder whether a Boolean was the right approach, or whether I should create a public method that I can call to set the Boolean, but either way, I can't figure out how to access the Boolean or the method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I worked it out, but please comment if what I have done is in any way a bodge.

I have left the class code as per the question, but added to the code i nteh main activity.

Class code therefore remains:

```
package com.domain.mypackage;

import android.net.Uri;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.webkit.WebResourceRequest;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;

public class nonInteractiveWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {

    public boolean canBrowseAmazonSites = false;

    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideKeyEvent (WebView view, KeyEvent event) {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, WebResourceRequest request) {
        String host = Uri.parse(view.getUrl()).getHost();

        if ("amzn.to".equals(host)) {
            return false;
        } else if (host != null && host.matches("(?i)^smile\\.amazon.*")) {
            return false;
        // Allow clicking of Amazon links
        } else if ( canBrowseAmazonSites && host != null && ( host.matches("(?i)^smile\\.amazon.*") || host.matches("(?i)^www\\.amazon.*") ) ) {
            return false;
        } else {
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

But now when I assign the `WebViewClient` to the `WebView` in the Activity, I declare it with an object name (rather than anonymously?).

I can then access the boolean from that named object as follows:

```
   viewBinding.amazonWebview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    viewBinding.amazonWebview.getSettings().setSupportZoom(true);
    viewBinding.amazonWebview.setWebViewClient(amazonWebViewClient = new nonInteractiveWebViewClient() {
        @Override
        public void onPageStarted(WebView _param1, String _param2, Bitmap _param3) {
            super.onPageStarted(_param1, _param2, _param3);
            viewBinding.progressBar.setIndeterminate(true);
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView _param1, String _param2) {
            super.onPageFinished(_param1, _param2);
            viewBinding.progressBar.setIndeterminate(false);
        }
    });

    amazonWebViewClient.canBrowseAmazonSites = true;
```

Where `amazonWebViewClient` is decalred in the Activity class as follows:

```
    nonInteractiveWebViewClient amazonWebViewClient;
```